# How to recover administrator password

Tags: macos, password, administrator

My friend has a 2011 iMac from his Dad, we play a computer game which has had an update which now means his old OS wouldn't run it, it needs at least Mountain Lion, so after lots of research he took the plunge and bought Mountain Lion from the Mac Store for £20... however once he received the email with the download link and pressed it, it asked for a password... however the login account does not have a password and his Dad does not know what the password could be...

Is there a way to download this new OS system which we have paid for without the password?

Comment: Which password is getting asked, a local one or the one for the App Store? If unsure, can you please add a screenshot of the password dialog?